# Yii user-centric Query Builder

Tags: php, yii

I'm generating a report view for users based off of queries from a MySQL database in my Yii app.

It started with one report but the requests are now coming in hard and fast. However, I've noticed that these requests don't usually require a change in the actual tables that are joined but the changes are only in the `SELECT` or `GROUP BY` criteria.

Is there a way for me to provide a checklist, for example, where they can select the columns they want to view and I can just run the query using that criteria ?

For example, one user selects name, min entry date, number of posts to generate a report with just those three columns which another can use lastname, max entry date, responses to generate that report.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible or if there is already an extension you can just addin?

Comment: I guess everything is possible. I'm asking if it's possible 'easily' OR if there is an extension.